# Different arrayadapter layouts (if and else)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My following Code gives the output of 3 "Blogtitles" (number didnt matter-its because the input, the "ifs" are only relevant for change layout). This 3 "Blogtitles" use 3 times the same Layout (Font Color Black). But i want different colors (see the comments in the code)

it never show the "listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);" the 3 "blogtitles" are showing in layout "listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);" although the first and the second "ifs" are true

Ye i´am very newbie at android... And please forgive me, for my bad english

```
for(int i=0; i< posts.length();i++ ) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            this.title = post.optString("title");


            arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.mytextview, blogTitles1);
            arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, blogTitles2);



            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neune") && title.contains(this.id.toLowerCase())) { 
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1); //get overwritten by array adapter2
                    blogTitles[i] = title;    //for example green                
            }


            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neune") ) {
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);//this one overwrites array adapter1
                    blogTitles[i] = title;//for example black
            }


            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neuja")&& title.contains(this.id.toLowerCase())) {
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
                    blogTitles[i] = title;//for example green
            }


            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("neuja") ) {
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
                    blogTitles[i] = "Dieser Artikel";//for example black
            }


            if (title.toLowerCase().contains("ganz")) { 
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
                    blogTitles[i] = "asd" //for example black                 
            }


        }
```

Comment: Hint: read "clean code" by Robert Martin; and read about "single layer of abstraction" principle. Your code could make good use of that.

Comment: why is this code not clean?and what you mean exactly with single layer of abstraction?->no solution for that what i want?

Comment: OK, to be precise here: "clean code" has nothing to do with the issue you are facing; I am not commenting on your concrete question; but on the perceived quality of your source code. "Clean code" focuses on rules that help writing **readable** code. You see, in my eyes, your code looks so un-clean; that I don't even feel tempted to study it in detail. It just hurts my eyes. And for single-layer - just google it. It is a rule that basically tells you to not put an if in an if in a for in a try block.

Comment: thx for feedback. hopefully it is better now to read... i cant change the try block because its essential for the "JSONObject" (i have no glue how to work around this without a "try")

Comment: I don't understand what the code you gave has to do with your question about adapters. Please edit your question to include code that is relevant to your question.